# how to design a circuit to measure in battery?

Tags: batteries, pcb-design, current-measurement, battery-chemistry

the main goal is to design an electric circuit with low energy

Comment: I could answer: *Study to be a circuit designer (possibly an EE even) and then design the circuit.* But I don't think that's the answer you're looking for. When I was a boy/student I looked at all the circuits I could get my hands on, mainly from books, magazines and datasheets (it was before the Internet age). Now with internet you do not even have to leave your computer so start searching for a schematic, then feel free to come back and discuss it here. We're not here to provide you with circuit solutions when you can easily find them yourself.

Comment: In the time it took you to type that, you could have googled 'current measurement circuit' and got thousands of examples, explanations and the like. You can't expect people to do your work for you when you can't even figure out how to google something

Comment: One issue I have is that the title does not match the question as asked... So, if you can't ask the correct question, you won't get the right answer...

Comment: Looks like he asked a similar question a few days ago too: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339137/how-to-design-a-circuit-to-measure-the-remaining-energy-in-battery

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of "[how to Design a circuit to measure the remaining energy in battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339137/how-to-design-a-circuit-to-measure-the-remaining-energy-in-battery)" question by the same OP [as *MCG* pointed out]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to www.google.com

Step 2: Type in 'Current measurement circuit'

Step 3: Pick from the thousands of examples and explanations. The amount of info you will get on something as simple as current measurement is much more than any one answer on here would give.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you a better hint then just Google it.

Simplest current sense technique is placing a shunt resistor of a known value in series with your main circuit. Measure the voltage drop across this resistor and using Ohms law you should be able to convert this voltage to a current.

Another hint: this is not the most power efficient. But it's a start on the fundamentals.

A good Primer:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01332B.pdf

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: The reason my answer is use google, and why other people commenting mentioned researching, is because of the amount of people that don't do any research and expect people here to do it all for them. If we did everything for these people, they will never learn to do things themselves

Comment: When you google anything, there is a lot of information out there.  Some of it good and some of it bad.  This can be overwhelming to newbies.  So I believe it is important to use our experience to help POINT someone in the right direction and offer guidance to nudge them in the right direction.